# How to tell if Type has been generated by the yield return? How to create an instance of this class?

Tags: c#, reflection, types, .net-assembly, yield-return

1. I'm reflecting over an `Assembly` and there are some types which have been generated by `yield return`, is there a reliable way to filter them out?
2. There's no default constructor for the `Type` generated by `yield return`. It is a `class` and not a value type. How to make an instance of this class?

The generated type-name looks like this:
`SomeNamespace.RootMode+<GetMouseArrow>d__1`, where `RootMode` is the class name and `GetMouseArrow` is the function which has `yield-return` in it.

---

**Use case**: Serialization of *complete* state of a running application, including the state of `yield-return` statements

---

**UPDATE:**

1. Types generated by the `yield return` have a single public constructor which takes `int` as parameter. This is the state variable used to determine *where* in the function the `IEnumerator` is.
2. The generated classes are `private` and `sealed`, they implement a set of `IEnumerator*/IEnumerable*` interfaces.
3. The generated class has `[CompilerGenerated]` attribute set to it.

Comment: Generated by yield return?  How would you expect to either detect or have this be an issue?  If that's the case, why not filter out anything "generated" by a foreach or a for loop but not a while?  What it really sounds like you need to be worried about is if the type is anonymous, not if it was "generated" specifically by a yield return.

Comment: Yes, a new type(a class) is generated by the compiler for each yield-return statement. This class has three fields __state; __current; and __this; This class stores the state of the IEnumerator to know where to continue when IEnumerator (moveNext/current) is called. When you call Assembly.GetTypes() function it will include this type and I have to filter them out to handle them seperately.

Comment: I also need to be able create instances of this type to copy over and transform their fields (private ones too!).

Comment: Are the types anonymous or not?  If they're anonymous the properties are read only and cannot be changed, nor should they.  As it stands right now, without code, it is really hard to determine what would actually help your situation

Comment: The assembly is compiled run-time. It can contain literally all-sorts of types. The types are acquired at run-time using Assembly.GetTypes(). Moreover the types are manipulated using direct field access. Properties are ignored. The code which does the actual work with types is generated run-time by Expression Trees.

Comment: As far as I can tell - anonymous types - as far as System.Reflection is concerned - doesn't exist. It's just a syntactical sugar.

Comment: It seems you found answers to your questions. You should post them as an answer and then accept it, instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `[CompilerGenerated]` is most likely what you want. It's used not just for "iterator methods" (the name of the feature you're describing), but if you're looking to *filter out* types, you probably want to filter out all compiler-generated types (which would also include types generated for anonymous methods, and for `async` methods).

As far as instantiating an instance of such a class, you can use reflection, but of course you'll have to identify the parameter to pass and use the appropriate constructor overload. Without the default constructor, the usual serialization techniques won't work; you'll have to implement something yourself to handle this explicitly. I.e. get the appropriate value from within the class instance when serializing, and then pass it to the constructor…of course, to fully restore the state of the class, you'll need to serialize all the private fields and restore those again on deserialization, all via reflection.

I hope the value of implementing this is very high to you, because the cost sure will be. :)